# Possible solution for the magic square of squares problem

Tags: magic-square

I was fiddling around with this problem for 3x3 magic squares after seeing another Numberphile video and I got to a point where I'm not sure where the error in proving no such magic squares exists is, so I would appreciate someone pointing it out.

So, consider a generic magic square of the following form:

$\begin{pmatrix} a^2 & b^2 & c^2 \\ d^2 & e^2 & f^2 \\ g^2 & h^2 & i^2 \end{pmatrix}$

and a sum $s$. Using some simple arithmetic and the basic properties of magic squares (the rows, columns and diagonals sum up to $s$), we can see that any magic square of squares can be written as follows:

$\begin{pmatrix} 2 t^2 - \frac{b^2+d^2}{2} & b^2 & t^2 - \frac{b^2-d^2}{2} \\ d^2 & t^2 & 2t^2-d^2 \\ t^2 + \frac{b^2-d^2}{2} & 2 t^2-b^2 &  \frac{b^2+d^2}{2} \end{pmatrix}$

where $t^2=\frac{s}{3}$. Now, we can see that the elements in the second diagonal form an arithmetic sequence, and since we know these should be square numbers, we know we can parameterize them using the following replacements ([Arithmetic sequence of squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruum#Parameterized_solution)):

$t^2 =(m^2+n^2)^2$

$\frac{b^2-d^2}{2} = 4 m n (m^2-n^2)$ - the congruum

Now, replacing the values of $t$ and $d$ in the matrix and simplifying the terms, we get the elements on the main diagonal to be:

$a^2=(m^2+n^2)^2+\left((m^2+n^2)^2+4 m n (m^2-n^2) - b^2\right)$

$e^2=(m^2+n^2)^2$

$i^2=(m^2+n^2)^2-\left((m^2+n^2)^2+4 m n (m^2-n^2) - b^2\right)$

Again, these are all squares and again form an arithmetic sequence so we can parameterize them in the same way, but since the middle element is already in parameterized  form, we know that the congruum of this sequence must be of the form $4 m n (m^2-n^2)$. And now we have two possibilities:

1. $(m^2+n^2)^2+4 m n (m^2-n^2) - b^2=4 m n (m^2-n^2)$

which gives $b^2=(m^2+n^2)^2$, but doing the replacement makes all the entries of the magic square equal, or

2. $(m^2+n^2)^2+4 m n (m^2-n^2) - b^2=-4 m n (m^2-n^2)$

which when used to express $b^2$ and replace it in the magic square gives the second row to have all the same elements $(m^2+n^2)^2$, all the corner elements to be equal to $(m^2-2mn-n^2)^2$, and $b^2$ and $h^2$ to be equal to $(m^2-n^2)^2-8 m n (m^2-n^2)$.

So, the conclusion is that the only magic squares of squares are the ones with at most three distinct values.

Comment: If it works, you might have proven an important conjecture (in the fact  that it stayed open for quite a long time)

Comment: That's a BIG if.

Comment: I did not read it completely but it seems you have made restrictions on $t$ and subsequently $s$ by assuming $t$ can be written as the sum of two squares. Is this alright?

Comment: So, according to this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruum#Parameterized_solution, this parameterization is given due to the fact that these three numbers must be squares and they are a fixed distance apart (called the congruum).

Comment: I can't find a problem in this. I'd suggest to try and write a formal proof in some interactive theorem prover, and then you'd either find the error or be confidant in the result

Comment: Oh, OK. I'm definitely not equipped to do that but I'm willing to try...

Comment: From the wikipedia page: "Additionally, multiplying a congruum by a square number produces another congruum, whose progression of squares is multiplied by the same factor". You might have missed that

Comment: You are correct, I did miss that. I'm not sure it would make a difference, though, since the factor would just propagate and the same conclusion would arise. I think. However, it probably doesn't even matter since Gerry Myerson pointed out a flaw in reasoning.

Comment: The factor does make a difference - I've given a couple of examples below

Answer (score 4):

> Again, these are all squares and again form an arithmetic sequence so we can parameterize them in the same way, but since the middle element is already in parameterized form, we know that the congruum of this sequence must be of the form $4mn\left(m^2−n^2\right)$

Unfortunately, this conclusion doesn't hold. Firstly, you're missing the other part of the parameterisation in that article; arithmetic progressions of squares can also have the form
$$t^2 \left(m^2+n^2\right)^2 - 4mnt^2 \left(m^2−n^2\right),t^2\left(m^2+n^2\right)^2,t^2 \left(m^2+n^2\right)^2 + 4mnt^2\left(m^2−n^2\right)$$

So, for example, the squares $25,625,1225$ are in AP, but so are the squares $289,625,841$.

Also the parameterisation isn't necessarily unique; for example since $65=1^2+8^2=4^2+7^2$, we can generate the two distinct triples of squares in AP $529,4225,7921$ and $2209,4225,6241$.

Answer (score 2):

$e^2=(m^2+n^2)^2$, but $e^2$ may have another entirely different expression as the square of a sum of two squares, $e^2=(u^2+v^2)^2$, with $\{u,v\}\ne\{m,n\}$.

As a general rule, longstanding conjectures will not be solved via high school algebra.

Comment: You are completely correct with your comment about high school algebra... So, the wrong assumption is the step of equating the two congrua?

Comment: I disagree with your last sentence. Personally, I think that trying difficult open problems, even if your skill level is not peak, can always be productive. Just think of the two high schoolers thet proved Phytagoras using elementary trigonometry. You can't know in advance that every effort will be useless. @gerrymyerson

Comment: @Zima Pythagoras' theorem was not an open problem at the time so it seems irrelevant to the disscussion. Additionally all they did was produce a (possibly) novel method of deriving the statement. I cannot think of a single case of an actual longstanding, well known conjecture being solved by someone without a relevant qualification (I'm not saying it hasn't happened, just I can't think of any). Of course it is true that you can't know in advance what effort will be useless, but the statement was that as a "general rule" it is not going to happen, which I agree with.

Comment: Well, milin, I didn't look at anything else, so I'm in no position to say whether that's the only mistake.

Comment: @Zima, there's nothing wrong with trying difficult open problems. But if you think you've solved a longstanding problem, it's your job to search long and hard to try to find an error in your work.

Comment: Well, one is enough. Thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: @Fishbane, there's a thread, I don't remember whether it's here or at MathOverflow, on results by amateurs. The one I recall well is the work of Marjorie Rice, who found some new pentagons that tile the plane, long after it was thought that all types were already known. She had no mathematical qualifications.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Fair enough. I still agree with your sentiment, but thank you for the example.

Comment: @Fishbane showing Pythagoras could or could not be derived using trigonometry was an open problem, so I don't see why it is irrelevant. Though, I agree that 99.9999 % of the times if you prove something very difficult using basic maths, you should look for an error in your work, I still think it's worthy to give it a try.

Comment: It can be difficult to find where a mistake has been made in reasoning, it seems this is a reasonable forum to ask for checks on. Sorry, I'm relatively new here, but this seems a much better use of the platform than the dozen or so "please do my homework" questions that crop up each day.

Comment: @Zima It isn't relevant anymore given the example from Gerry Myerson, but having had a quick look Jason Zimba produced a derivation of pythagoras' theorem in 2009 which is reliant only on the angle difference formulas for sin and cosine making this not an open problem. It can be found in Forum Geometricorum Volume 9 pages 275-278. A quick version can be found here https://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/TrigProof.shtml. (Additionally the fact that you were referencing an open problem associated with pythagoras' theorem was not at all obvious in your comment)

Comment: Pythagoras' theorem is an irrelevant example because it is so easy that it is no surprise if anyone solves it without having known a proof before. This is very different with long outstanding open problems.

Answer (score 0):

The magic square is sometimes used to let children wonder about numbers. Less common are questions to practice disproving a statement i.e. finding the flaw. These examples often only use high school algebra. A similar example.

Richard Guy noted that we can write the problem with three squares $x_1^2$, $x_3^2$, and $x_5^2$ as follows (also referred to as the Lucas form)

$\begin{pmatrix}
x_1^2 & x_2^2 & x_3^2 \\
x_4^2 & x_5^2 & x_6^2 \\
x_7^2 & x_8^2 & x_9^2 \\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1^2 & 3x_5^2-x_1^2-x_3^2 & x_3^2  \\
x_5^2+x_3^2-x_1^2 & x_5^2 & x_5^2+x_1^2-x_3^2 \\  
2x_5^2-x_3^2 & x_1^2+x_3^2-x_5^2 & 2x_5^2-x_1^2  \\
\end{pmatrix}$

whereby all squares are uneven, and $x_8^2=x_1^2+x_3^2-x_5^2$ is the smallest square.

There are many relations, for instance, the three sets of two relations below

| # | relation |
| --- | --- |
| 1a | $(x_1^2)^2=(x_6x_8)^2+(x_5^2-x_3^2)^2$ |
| 1b | $2x_1^2=x_6^2+x_8^2$ |
| 2a | $(x_3^2)^2=(x_4x_8)^2+(x_5^2-x_1^2)^2$ |
| 2b | $2x_3^2=x_4^2+x_8^2$ |
| 3a | $(x_5^2)^2=(x_4x_6)^2+(x_3^2-x_1^2)^2$ |
| 3b | $2x_1^2=x_6^2+x_8^2$ |

All Pythagorean triples can be written as $a =h \cdot (m^{2}-n^{2}),\ \,b=h \cdot (2mn),\ \,c=h \cdot (m^{2}+n^{2})$ where $0<n<m$ are coprime integers, and both are not odd, and $0<h$ is an integer such that $\gcd(a,b,c)=h$.

The first relation is a Pythagorean triple, and hence there exist positive integers $m>n$ such that $x_1^2= h(m^2+n^2)$, $x_6x_8=h(m^2-n^2)$ and $x_5^2-x_3^ 2=2hmn$. Note that $x_6x_8=2hmn$ is not possible as all squares are uneven. As $x_1^2$ is a square, we can ignore the parameter $h$ and consider it to be a part of the parameters $m$ and $n$.

We can solve 1a+1b via the polynomial $z^2-(x_6^2+x_8^2)z+(x_6x_8)^2=z^2-2(m^2+n^2)z+(m^2-n^2)^2=0$ to yield $x_1^2=m^2+n^2$,  $x_6=m+n$,  $x_8=m-n$ and $x_5^2 -x_3^2=2mn$.

In the same manner, we can solve the following two relations 2a+2b, which yields that $x_3^2=m'^2+n'^2$,  $x_4=m'+n'$,  $x_8=m'-n'$ and $x_5^2 -x_1^2=2m'n'$.

We conclude that $x_8=m-n=m'-n'$. Furthermore, $x_5^2=\frac{1}{2}(x_4^2+x_6^2)=\frac{1}{2}\big((m+n)^2+(m'+n')^2\big)$.

Similarly, we can solve the next two relations 3a+3b. Hence, for numbers $m_*>n_*$ we have that $x_5^2=m_*^2+n_*^2$,  $x_4=m_*+n_*$,  $x_6=m_*-n_*$ and $x_3^2 -x_1^2=2m_*n_*$.

The solutions imply the following conditions:

- $x_4=m_*+n_*=m'+n'$ en $x_6=m_*-n_*=m+n$
- $x_3^2-x_1^2=2m_*n_*=2m'n'-2mn=(x_5^2-x_1^2)-(x_5^2-x_3^2)$

Hence $m_*,n_*=m'+n,n'-n$.

Also holds $x_5^2=m_*^2+m_*^2=\frac{1}{2}(x_4^2+x_6^2)=\frac{1}{2}\big(( m+n)^2+(m'+n')^2\big)$. This is only true if $-m'n - n^2 - m'n' + nn'=0$. This yields $n'=-n\big(\frac{m'+n}{m'-n}\big)$, hence $n'<0$ as $n<m<m'$. This contradicts the fact that $n’$ is positive.

**Exercise**: find the flaw(s).

Comment: If you are asking a question, it';s best to post it as a new question, rather than as an answer to an old question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I tried to post a question, however, the syntax "begin{pmatrix} .. end{pmatrix}" does not render correctly. Any suggestion on how to solve this?

Comment: Whatever works in an answer, should work in a question (unless maybe you tried to use fancy math formatting in the title). You could have a look at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference